# Username urls like Twitter, FriendFeed, Facebook, etc. in a Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm thinking about defining Restful urls for a new project (developed with Ruby On Rails).
I like the simple and clean urls of the most famous web 2.0 services like "twitter.com/username". Not talking about problems in routing configuration (I want to do that with resources not using dirty "map.connect" overrides), the very problem is: how preserve words that you want to use for your pages (such as: website.com/help, website.com/api, etc.)? I don't want to think all the possibilities at time 0 (also because it is quite impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to be on the safe side - think about a single prefix (`map.with_options :prefix => 'do/'`) for all your custom stuff, so that all your controllers/actions will be prefixed like this

```
http://example.com/do/:controller/:action/:whatever
```

So you would just have to block the `do` as username and will have the freedom to do whatever you like after that prefix.

Comment: Hi Marcel,
yes I'm thinking about adding a short path, also possible using :as option (:as => :do in your example), but do you think that a correct RESTful resource must be semantically speaking for itself? For example if I'm talking about users is it correct to use the path http://example.com/do/username instead of http://example.com/users/username. I now that these are subtleties but why all the bigs of web 2.0 "complicate their lives" using urls like http://twitter.com/username?

Answer (score 3):

Routes are prioritized by the moment they're declared. The first matching declared route will be the one executed.

So if you have :

```
map.resources :users
map.profile ':nickname', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

If you go to `/users`, you'll be on the `map.resources :users` route because that's the first one to match.
When you go to `/zetarun`, you'll be routed to `map.profile ':nickname', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'` because that's the first route to match.

Then for the user profiles, you can do the following :

Define all your resources in the routes for all your controllers.
And at the end of the resources, you add the user profile resource.

So when a prefix is user by a controller, it's routed first by any route that exists.
And only the not routed url remains for user profiles.

Don't forget to add a "reserved nickname" validation on the user registration to avoid someone taking a nickname that won't give him a profile as there's something else on that url.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your response. It works but when I enter in someone profile and click a link (for example poiting to user images) I have the original resources link mapped in routes (i.e.: /users/zetarun/photos), if I want to change all the routes to begin only with /username, I have to add some other routing rules (in override at the resources rules). But what that made me paranoid is the "reserved nickname" validation...How can I know right now all the url that I want to use in the future (and blocking users taking these)...it's quite impossible, I know...